# Tracking active users on Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Apologies if this question has already been asked but I have no been able to find it. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to track how often a user opens my app if they're already logged in. Firebase only shows the last time they're signing in, but not if they're already signed in so I don't know when they've actually been opening my app last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no presence tracking built into Cloud Firestore. It just doesn't match well to the protocol that Firestore uses to communicate between client and server.

The simplest way to get this working is to use the Realtime Database, and potentially synchronize the information to Cloud Firestore from there. For a walkthrough of this (quite involved) scenario have a look at the [Firestore documentation on building a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).